# Extract two numbers from string using formula

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have formula to extract numbers from Google XML response, that can be:

1. `9 часов 24 минут`
2. `10 h 0 min`
3. `9 h 20 min`
4. `11 h 13 min`
5. `10 Std 55 min`
6. `9 timmar 5 min`
7. `19 min`

Here is current formula (value is in BZ1):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(IF(FIND("min";BZ1;1)=11;MID(BZ1;FIND("min";BZ1;1)-2;1);MID(BZ1;FIND("min";BZ1;1)-3;2)))<30; VALUE(LEFT(BZ1;FIND("h";BZ1;1)-2))&","&5;VALUE(LEFT(BZ1;FIND("h";BZ1;1)-2))+1);"")
```

Formula rounds hours and minutes to hours, for example

- `1 h 39 min` -> `2`
- `10 h 12 min` -> `10,5`
- `9 h 20 min` -> `9,5`

There is a problem that it is not able to take in consideration language changes for `hours` and `min`.

Is there any possibility to make it work so that it will:

- If there is only number (case `19 min`) -> extract number
- If there are two numbers (case `1 h 39 min`) -> extract first number as hours, then from last two spaces number as minutes

---

**EDIT:**

Check how many numbers in cell (target in CA25):

```
SUM(LEN(CA25)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};)))>1
```

If more than 1

```
LEFT(CA25;(FIND(" ";CA25;1)-1))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;" ";REPT(" ";50));100;50))
```

If less than 1

```
LEFT(CA25;SUM(LEN(CA25)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;{"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"};""))))
```

All together

```
=IF(SUM(LEN(CA25)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};)))>1;LEFT(CA25;(FIND(" ";CA25;1)-1))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;" ";REPT(" ";50));100;50));LEFT(CA25;SUM(LEN(CA25)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CA25;{"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"};"")))))
```

This gives as output:

[image]

Now these need to be converted to hours and rounded up to one hour

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here is formula (target BZ1):

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(BZ1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(BZ1;" ";""))>2;LEFT(BZ1;(FIND(" ";BZ1;1)-1))+IF(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(BZ1;" ";REPT(" ";50));100;50))<60;1;1);IF(LEFT(BZ1;SUM(LEN(BZ1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(BZ1;{"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"};""))))<60;1;1));"")
```

Comment: Any interest in a VBA solution ??

Comment: Yes, after investigating this issue at the moment I am starting to think it might be the only one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small user defined function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function Tyme(inpt As String) As Double
    Dim arr, U As Long
    Tyme = 0
    arr = Split(inpt, " ")
    U = UBound(arr)
    If U = 0 Then Exit Function
    If U = 1 Then
        Tyme = CDbl(arr(0))
    Else
        Tyme = CDbl(arr(0)) + CDbl(arr(2)) / 60#
    End If
End Function
```

It:

- is language-independent
- returns an **un-rounded** floating point value *(hours)*

Some examples:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=Tyme(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

**NOTES:**

1. rounding should be applied **outside** the udf
2. it would be easy to modify the udf to handle seconds as well
3. it would be easy to modify the udf to return true Excel time rather than floating point hours

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you use a VBA function? Seeing as in your examples there is always a space between the numbers and other characters, this should do it:

```
Public Function TimeInHoursRoundedUp(rng as Range)
    Dim var As Variant: var = Split(rng, " ")
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim hour As Integer: hour = 0
    For Each item In var
        If IsNumeric(item) Then
            If hour = 0 Then hour = hour + item Else hour = hour + 1
        End If
    Next item
    TimeInHoursRoundedUp = hour
End Sub
```

Then in your excel sheet you could simply write `=TimeInHoursRoundUp()` and input the cell reference inside the brackets.